# Getting error at console jQuery : not a function

Tags: jquery

In MVC I am getting following error :

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function

I just Installed the latest version of jQuery via NUGET. I'm getting stuck because of the above mentioned error.

Comment: Seeing your code would help here. What object are you using in the jQuery selector?

Comment: Also [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in jQuery 3, and replaced by [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).

Comment: Version of jQuery is pertinent in this case!

Comment: @DavidThomas it should be at min file or other

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced **andSelf()** with **addBack()** in jQuery min file .

Now working perfectly .

Comment: Please do not add an answer. Instead update your question with a note or just accept the answer  - in this case it was the comment of David that was answering

Answer (score 2):

Sir, the **andSelf()** is deprecated in version 1.8 and removed from 3.0. that's why the above error is occurred.
Here is some description: **https://api.jquery.com/andself/**